# SSH server disconnecting when valid auth request is provided and responding with seemingly invalid SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK

Tags: ssh

I use the `net-ssh` ruby library to connect to various servers. Around 2 months ago, a large subset of the servers we connect to stopped working, these servers belong to several major banks. We're seeing a "connection disconnected by remote host" error.

The problem seems to be that we can't agree on a signing algorithm - the banks SSH server is advertising it supports `ssh-rsa` and `rsa-sha-256` (verified with `ssh -Q sig`) however if we send anything except `ssh-rsa`, the connection crashes.

The tech support team at one of those banks told us "your SSH client is non-compliant", I've spent the last 2 months digging into this claim and believe the opposite (the banks server is non-compliant) is true, though that may not be the root cause of the issue.

Specifically - upon sending a `SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST` message with a PK alg of `rsa-sha2-256` and a signature alg of `rsa-sha2-256`, the server sends back a `SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK` with a PK alg of `ssh-rsa` - This seems to be a violation of the spec:

> The server MUST respond to this message with either
> SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE or with the following:
>
> ```
>  byte      SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK
>  string    public key algorithm name from the request
>  string    public key blob from the request
> ```

The only thing slightly suspicious is that from what I understand, the pk alg is *supposed* to be `sha-rsa` with a sig alg of `rsa-sha2-256`. We tried sending it that way and we get the same issue.

We can technically fix this issue by just changing the order we try the signature algorithms in to put `ssh-rsa` first, but it seems strange that we'd need to do this (not to mention I'd expect to see the same problem for `rsa-sha2-256` if we did).

Some questions:

1. Have I completely missed a signature algorithm handshake protocol?
2. Is the bank's SSH server wrong to send back a `SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_PK_OK` without the same PK alg we're sending?
3. Is the bank's SSH server wrong not to accept `rsa-sha2-256` when it advertises it accepts this algorithm

Comment: Welcome to the community. Have you tried increasing your DEBUG level?

Comment: Thanks! I have been using that level, this is how I got the info here (I also modified the code to print out the messages so I can see even more detail)

Comment: Have you tried using other clients, to confirm or counter their shift of blame onto your client?

Comment: From your client, can you run `ssh -v username@hostname.domain.tld`, and edit your question to post the output?

Comment: So I actually found the problem - they don't implement the `SSH_MSG_EXT_INFO` message, the spec is a little "loose" on what the default should be here, but it seems they're assuming that we'll send `ssh-rsa`. I still think they're not spec compliant because they just close the connection (no error, just kill). I modified net-ssh to send the  `ext-info-c` key exchange field, and then default to only support `ssh-rsa` if we don't get a EXT_INFO message back: https://github.com/znewsham/net-ssh/pull/1/files

Thanks for the help though!

Comment: The server does not 'advertise' what userkey algs it accepts except in EXT_INFO; `ssh -Q` shows the algs _your copy of ssh_ implements for various things without regard to any server whatsoever. Since 8308 EXT_INFO was created _because of_ 8332 rsa-sha2, I would indeed take nonsupport for it as a strong hint rsa-sha2 isn't supported either.